# How do I say, "I am willing to relocate", in my CV?

Tags: expressions

I'd like some help with my CV. I want to add one sentence below my name, telling the company that I am free to relocate to any city.
I am not a native speaker and I am not sure about this. 
Can anybody tell me how to say it? Which way is proper and professional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question actually has a sentence in its body which would work: "free to relocate". It's not a complete sentence but CVs often use fragments such as that for brevity. You might also say "willing to relocate", etc. @Robusto's "will relocate" works too but it sounds to me like you are saying that you already know that you are relocating at some point in the future.

Comment: Is it fine to say *disponibility to relocate*?

Comment: @santimirandarp I've never encountered that word in English and had to look it up. Stick with simpler language, like "available".

Answer (score 9):

Address the issue of relocation in a cover letter, rather than your CV, and tailor the description to the particular requirement of that position. A résumé or CV is a description of your previous experience, while a cover letter is where you should promote your suitability for a particular job - including requirements like relocation.

If for some reason it is absolutely impossible to provide a separate cover letter, consider adding a general Availability section with additional information such as dates you can begin working. "Willing to relocate" is a suitable phrase.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen *Open to relocation* in many resumes.

Answer (score 5):

One sentence, two words: "Will relocate."

Comment: But won't this also convey that I _will_ relocate (even if the job does not need it) to some other place sometime in the future?

Comment: @Nivas: No. It will be construed to mean that you are open to the possibility. It's just a shorthand way to say "I am willing to relocate if the job demands it." If it worries you, say something like that. Or put a positive spin to it: "I am willing to relocate for the right opportunity." That expresses your willingness to relocate but sets the bar high enough so that they realize they must have something good to offer before you will consider moving your household.

Comment: "I am willing to relocate for the right opportunity" sounds perfect :-)

Answer (score 4):

"willing to relocate" - you can add this to your personal profile