# How do I say "flexibility with time" on my CV?

Tags: expressions

Similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-do-i-say-i-am-willing-to-relocate-in-my-cv), but slightly different.

I'm trying to convey the willingness to work flexible hours.

I'm translating from Spanish for a friend of mine. A literal translation of  'disponibilidad horaria' is 'time availability' which doesn't sound right.

I'll make it 'willing to work flexible hours' as proposed by @Avon

Comment: "I am willing to work shifts" or words to that effect. But it's something you would normally add in a cover letter, not in a CV. Why send a CV if you were not available? If the applicant is single, young and in good health, I'd expect that person to work the hours that the position demands.

Comment: Putting to on side whether it makes sense to mention this on a CV (that is beyond the scope of this site), I would just say "I am willing to work flexible hours".

Comment: Less relevant, but could be helpful : http://www.lse.ac.uk/intranet/staff/humanResources/equalityAndDiversity/flexibleWorking/guidanceForRequestingFlexibleWorking.doc.

Comment: @Avon but am I correct in saying that is something you would say in a cover letter? Especially with the online Europass CV.  . GUI Junkie if you don't mind me pointing out; the phrase "willingness to work flexible hours" was already present in your question, so I suggested *shift* which is nevertheless perfectly valid, clear and unambiguous. http://jobsearch.about.com/od/temp-job/qt/temp-job-interview-7.htm

Comment: @Mari-LouA Some CVs are posted online for example for employers and recruiters to find candidates so it could be appropriate there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone who has had to plough through CVs, I recommend clarity and succinctness above all else: say what you mean and avoid any expressions that could be are at all colloquial or otherwise could be misunderstood.

I would simply say:

> I am willing to work flexible hours